# Custom user-agent string to get a better looking Facebook login

Tags: iphone, facebook, webview, titanium, user-agent

I currently have an app that uses a webview to show my website.
The webview is only allowed to access a certain page of my website and no other devices are allowed to access it.

I'm restricting this with a user agent that Titanium SDK gives me: **Titanium.userAgent**

> "Appcelerator Titanium/3.5.0 (iPhone Simulator/8.1; iPhone OS; en_US;)"

Unfortunately this gives me a fairly poor looking Facebook login when I go to login with Facebook on my website through the webview.

The Facebook login looks fine though if I use the default user agent from the webview (basically by not setting the user agent manually and just leaving it). But unfortunately, this default webview user agent is the same as any other mobile browsers user agent, so I can't tell them apart from the app or a mobile browser to redirect them to the correct places on my website.

And unfortunately on iOS, there's a bug in Titanium where you cannot get the default user agent (**webView.getUserAgent() or webView.userAgent** return undefined on iOS).

So I was wondering exactly what I need to do to my custom user agent string here:

> "Appcelerator Titanium/3.5.0 (iPhone Simulator/8.1; iPhone OS; en_US;)"

To make it so the Facebook login looks clean and smooth, because the above user agent, while it redirects my users to the correct place, gives me a poor looking Facebook login. What do I need to add to this string?

This is the default webview user agent string that gives me a good looking Facebook login page:

> ""Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_9_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B411"

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by simply appending the user agent I retrieved from my access logs to the one Titanium SDK gives me:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_9_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B411"